# OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture in android titanium

Tags: android, camera, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

In Titanium appcelerator, when I capture an image and show in an `ImageView`, image is not being shown, instead, below warning is being shown.

> [WARN] :   OpenGLRenderer: Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (1840x3264,  max=2048x2048)

How to solve this problem?
Whereas in tablet it is working fine, but in high resolution device its not working.

This one occurs when I insert an image into a `ImageView` when shot from camera or pick from the gallery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because different phones have different amounts of texture memory available depending on hardware, and their OpenGL version, this specific value is `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` and can be looked up per phone [here](http://www.glbenchmark.com/device.jsp?D=Google+Nexus+S&testgroup=gl&benchmark=glpro25) and in other places.

To work around this, convert the image to a blob and then resize it using a built-in function: [imageAsResized](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsResized), in the success callback after taking a picture.

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    ....
    success : function(e) {
        // Resized to a size that most phones should support
        var resizedImage = e.media.imageAsResized(1024, 1024);
        // Set the image view with the resized image
        imageView.image = resizedImage;
    },
    ....
});
```